# Passing variable args from macro to a function that expects va_list

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

```
#define exampleA(buf, args...) \
        exampleB(buf, ##args); \
    }

#endif
```

works where the exampleB function declaration is exampleB(char* buf, ...).
But I need to change the declaration as exampleB(char* buf, va_list args). How can change the marco accordingly?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a helper function, `exampleB(char *buf, ...)` which then sets up the `va_list` and then calls a second function, `exampleBva(char *buf, va_list args)` which does the actual work of processing the list of arguments.  One question that comes to mind is how do you know how many arguments and their types to actually process?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. In order to create a `va_list`, you need to have a variadic function. There is no portable facility to create a `va_list` object from a list of arguments.

It is quite common to write variadic functions in pairs: the outer function uses the facilities in `<stdarg.h>` to construct a `va_list`, and it passes that list directly to the function which does the work. You see that in the standarid I/O library, for example: `printf`/`vprintf`, `fprintf`/`vfprintf`, `snprintf`/`vsnprintf`, `scanf`/`vscanf`, etc.

And that's what you should do for your problem: write `exampleB` as the `va_list` form of `exampleA`.

Here, for example, is the entire implementation of the `fprintf` function extrated from the FreeBSD library, which can serve as a model of this style:

```
int
fprintf(FILE * __restrict fp, const char * __restrict fmt, ...)
{
    int ret;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    ret = vfprintf_l(fp, __get_locale(), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return (ret);
}
```

As you can see from that snippet, `vfprintf_l` (which takes a locale argument) is actually the implementation; all the other `*printf` functions are simple wrappers. (`printf`, for examples, calls `vfprintf_l` passing `stdin` and the locale argument.) That avoids having to traverse multiple wrappers in a single call, although modern optimising compilers are usually able to do that elimination automatically.

(See [lib/libc/stdio/fprintf.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdio/fprintf.c) for the full file in the FreeBSD source repository mirror on Github.)

Speaking of portability, `#define exampleA(buf, args...)` is a GCC extension which is not portable to most C implementations (although Clang implements it as well). You should use `__VA_ARGS__` as per standard C:

```
#define exampleA(buf, ...) \
        exampleB(buf, ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

Even better, if you can, replace the other GCC extension (`, ##`) with the newer standard `__VA_OPT__`:

```
#define exampleA(buf, ...) \
        exampleB(buf __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible the way you imagine it.
Let's consider a function `exampleX(char *,...)`: the arguments you pass must live somewhere and let's say they are pushed to the stack. The `va_list` macros know that and can access them from there. The moment you leave that function, the arguments cannot be assumed to be on the stack anymore.
Thus, you may **not** write a helper function like `va_list getArgs(char*x,...) { /* use va_start and return the va_list */ }` and pass that `va_list` to `exampleB`.

The only thing I can think of is to write a trampoline function such as

```
void callExampleB(char * buf, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, buf);
  exampleB(buf, ap);
  va_end(ap);
}
```

and call that in your macro.